# RAILS -- How To: Hide a link_to in a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have this helper in my user index... all good.

```
<%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user) %>
```

What i'd like to do is have that helper buried/hidden in pencil glyph that links to the opening of a modal which in turn is in the edit_user_path.

I can get everything to work if I do this

```
<td class= "centre" >
<p  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="edit" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" 
<%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user) %> >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</button>
</p>
</td>
```

The link is physically in the button but also visible on the page...How should I be doing this

Hours later...EDIT...

I can now get everything working with the username hidden and only the glyph showing (which is correct) but by removing the `user.name` I now render a blank form no user content. I should say at this point that both signup and edit are sharing a form partial

this almost works, but renders a blank form for signup not edit... and its not very rails

```
<td class= "centre" >
                        <p  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                        </p>
                        </td>
```

Comment: You can not place a link in a button, that is invalid HTML. And what you actually want to ask here, I didn’t understand.

Comment: Its ERB embedded ruby

Comment: if you need an icon inside a link and you want to show modal when clicking it, you just wrap an icon with `link_to` block and put all data attributes to `link_to`